# Filipino partner applying for Schengen visa while processing marriage annulment

Tags: filipino-citizens, weddings, schengen-visas

I will explain briefly our situation. My Filipino partner is still married in tje Philippines (because divorce doesn't exist there), but separated 8 years ago from his wife. We are 3 years in a relationship and we are starting now the annulment process for his marriage but this is a long process. We would like to go to Europe on a Schengen visa to visit my family.

On the application form you need to fill out his marital status. What would be the best to fill out:
- Fill out still married and give as travel reason that he's just visiting a good friend?
- Or fill out other and write that we started the annulment process, add proof of the process with the application and as travel reason that he's visiting his girlfriend and family?

Any answer is appreciated, it's a complicated situation with the annulment process, I just really want him to see my home and meet my family.

Answer (score 1):

The key is to be truthful. In countries with legal divorce, lots of people are separated while the divorce goes through, and may be in other relationships at the same time, so I don't think that this situation would raise any particular red flags with the Schengen authorities. (Of course, since he is coming to visit a romantic partner, this may generate the usual concerns about overstaying.) Based on what you have said, I think the most honest answer would be to check that he is married, but then specify that he is separated but in the process of getting an annulment.